# RStudio - Run lines of code without opening up next code section

Tags: rstudio

When I run lines of code using Ctrl + Enter and I hit the end of the code section, it automatically opens the next code section. I don't want the next section to open because they keep me organized. Is there a way to run lines of code but not have the next code section open? I can open code sections manually if I want to.

Comment: use shift+enter

Comment: Shift + enter just enters me a new line. Is there a checkbox somewhere that I need to check?

Comment: Yes it will enters you to a new line. Write your next code there. when you are done press enter, then it will execute all the lines and print all the respective outputs.

Comment: I don't want to write more code, I want to execute lines that are already there. I don't want extra enter lines in my code.

When I do shift+enter as you said, it simply acts as if I hit enter. It does not execute any lines.